# Link an unknown number of object files in a batch using gcc

Tags: batch-file, gcc, batch-processing

I have an unknown number of object files in a directory all of them named compile_to_cX.o , where X is a value from 1 to the number of object files in this directory. I want to link them using gcc, and the final result to be equivalent to something like:

```
  gcc -Xlinker -no-as-needed compile_to_c1.o ... compile_to_c1N.o -x none
  strip a.out
```

I tried using fors and environment variables but none worked.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there other `.o` files in the directory besides the compile_to_c files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `dir` is run without the `/b` option, the number of files it finds will be displayed at the bottom. Since you can filter `dir` on file extensions and there will be no other .o files except the ones you want, you can simply take the first space-delimited token of the file count string at the bottom of the `dir` output.

From there, you can use a `for /L` loop to build a string that contains all of the files you need to compile.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Get the number of .o files from the dir listing
for /f "tokens=1" %%A in ('dir *.o^|find "File(s)"') do set o_files=%%A

:: Build a string with all of the .o files (up to 512 due to string length limitations)
for /L %%A in (1,1,!o_files!) do set "o_string=!o_string! compile_to_c%%A.o"

:: Run gcc and strip (remove the echos if your strings look correct)
echo gcc -Xlinker -no-as-needed !o_string! -x none
echo strip a.out
pause
```

Comment: I understood everything. Thanks for your guidance SomethingDark , it is highly appreciated.